# SimpleModal content isn't loading in IE8 when CSS overflow is set to "scroll" or "auto"

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, overflow, simplemodal

I'm using simplemodal on a [website](http://www.valentina-garcia.com/home.html) I'm developing.  Everything was working fine across all browsers until I added "overflow: auto;" to my simplemodal CSS as such:

```
#simplemodal-container {height:90%; width:80%; color:#fff; overflow:
```

auto;}

I get the scrollbars when needed in FF, Safari, and Chrome just fine, but when I look at it in IE8 (haven't tried IE6 or IE7), most if not all of the content of the modal is missing.  It appears to be spinning as though it's waiting for the server, but nothing happens.

I've looked everywhere online for an answer to this issue, but haven't been able to find anyone else who's having the same issue.

Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I doubt very much whether that has to do with that CSS. You are 100% sure it works when you remove it? Can you show some Javascript code? Have you tried inspecting the page with IE8's developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Pekka, thanks for taking a look.  I was sure that it wasn't the javascript, because one of the buttons, (resume) links to a simple html doc with a table and that wasn't even showing up.

But I think I've figured it out!

In the CSS, there were also some opacity settings, which I pretty much copied over from the simplemodal website.  But one of the settings was an IE workaround that was throwing errors whenever I validated the page.  So about 5 minutes ago, I thought, "hm.  I wonder if I get rid of those opacity settings if that might do the trick."  I wasn't really using them anyway - I had set the opacity of my modal window to 100%.  So I just got rid of the settings, and now it works in IE.  Go figure.

On the "images" modal, my thumbnails are getting cut off in IE, so I do have one more thing to figure out, but at least it's showing up now!

HOO-RAY.